# Are the stun/etc chances normalized for weapon speed?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've tried building a stun-proc oriented gear and spec, focusing a lot on attack speed and fast weapons. However, attack speed seems to not affect the effectiveness of this spec. My impression is that I proc stuns much less often when I equip a very fast weapon.

Does anyone know if hit-effect-chances are normalized with regards to attack speed?

Comment: There's no evidence that they are...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aren't. You get the same proc chance regardless of your weapon speed.

Check out http://www.lurkerlounge.com/forums/thread-13842.html, they have a discussion about stunlocking monsters.

Do note that crowd-control effects on bosses do not last as long, and on higher difficulties even normal monsters are more resilient to crowd-control.